# Patt undecided?

Tags: learning, stalemate

I am very new to chess, and I fear that this question is very stupid.

I played this game in "easy" mode, and I destroyed a lot of pieces of the counter party.

Now, I wanted to destroy their king. But the game says "Patt - undecided". What does "undecided" mean?

Every move which his king will do, will make him lose the game. But why didn't I win then?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means the position is stalemate. By chess rules if one side is to move and is unable to move and is not in check then the game ends in a draw. That is what happened here to you.

Comment: Yes, I realized that black cannot move their king without being in check again. But what is the difference between patt and Checkmate ? In Checkmate, the party cannot move without losing their king - exactly this is happening in my patt situation, too, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: The difference is in checkmate the King must be in check, which is not the case in your game.

Answer (score 1):

These are the very basic rules of chess.  You should check a chess manual to be sure you know them.  A direct attack on the king is a check.  If you cannot get out of check somehow - by capture of the attacking piece, interposition or flight, then your king is checkmated and the game is over.  If it is your turn to move and you cannot legally move the king or anything else without going into check, then the game is a draw by stalemate, one of the numerous ways a game can be drawn,  The manual will explain all of these as well (triple repetition of position, perpetual check, insufficient mating material, exceeding the 50 move rule when no piece has been captured or pawn moved for 50 moves, and draw by agreement).

Comment: Downvoted as it did not add anything to my answer.